# How to programmatically change css of gridpanel's cell

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two distinct gridpanels and throughout my code, whenever value of one of the cells in Grid1 changes I want to be able to change value of certain cells in the Grid2,
How can I change the css of the second grid from within the Grid1.

The following allows me to change the css for an entire row in Grid2 but I need to be able to change the css for a cell of Grid2 row: 2, column 3

```
var Grid2Store= Ext.data.StoreManager.get("MainComparisonStore");
Grid2.getView().addRowCls(Grid2Store.getAt(2), 'orange-bar');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a hold of the element and you can use `cellElement.addCls('orange-bar');`.  See [Ext.dom.Element.addCls()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-addCls) documentation.  I put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuVET/10/) for you to see an example.  Just click the "Test" button in the grid toolbar.

Here is the code that does the work.  It is hard coded to add a class to column 1, row 1.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('myGrid');
var column = grid.columns[1];
var record = grid.store.getAt(1);
var cell = grid.getView().getCell(record, column);
cell.addCls('orange-bar');
```

[Here (Sencha Forum)](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136121-Grid-getCell-function) is some discussion on how to get the cell.  This is what I used to put together my example.  You can see how you could make a helper like getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex) pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, however I was not able to get it working as I didn't know how to get the Element. And as for the links, in all the links you mentioned, the grid is accessed on "renderer" or as in some other events within the grid itself. However, my need is abit different. Think of it as if within my application I need to get the grid and change the css for a certain cell, how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need something similar to this: var grid = Ext.getCmp('idGrid2'); grid.getView().getCell(rowInx, columnIndx).addCls('orange-bar'); - This is not correct but just gets the idea accrossed, any help would be much appreciated